# Use Keras Model on new data

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I successfully trained a ConvNet in Keras, and now I'd like to apply it on new data.

Sure, I can use model.save and load_model, but as this loads my whole model for every classification, it takes really long. Is there a more elegant way to do so?

I tried to "rebuild" my model via saving the weights and biases and applying them on my data, together with the activation functions I used. However, I don't obtain the same results like when using load_model, so I must have made a mistake ...

Is this rebuilding approach correct, or is there a more elegant way?

EDIT: I added my code, hope it's understandable ...

```
# sl: List containing for each layer: number of parameter matrices (=2 for conv or fully 
# connected layer, =0 for flatten layer) & shapes of the matrices
# weight_list_lc: List containing my weight matrices
# biases_list_lc: List containing my biases
def Is_Trip_ConvNet(inp):
    n_layers = len(sl)
    curr_dim = inp.shape
    for l in range(1,n_layers):
        if sl[l][0] > 0: # weights available
            weights = np.array(weight_list_lc[l-1])
            weights = weights.reshape(np.array(sl[l][1])) # correct shape 
            biases = bias_list_lc[l-1]
            if len(sl[l][1]) == 3: # ConvLayer
                field_size = sl[l][1][0]
                n_nodes = int(curr_dim[0]-field_size+1)
                n_filt = sl[l][1][2]
                out = np.zeros((n_nodes,n_filt))
                for n in range(0,n_nodes):
                    for f in range(0,n_filt):
                        out[n,f] = np.sum(np.multiply(inp[n:n+field_size,:],weights[:,:,f]))
                    out[n,:] = out[n,:]+biases
            else: # Fully Connected Layer
                out = inp.dot(weights)
                out = out + biases
            if l == n_layers-1: # Output Unit
                out = 1/(1+np.exp(-out)) # Sigmoid
            else:
                out = out*(out>0) # ReLU
        else: # no weights available --> Flatten Layer
            out = inp.reshape(-1)
        inp = out
        curr_dim = inp.shape
    return (out > 0.5)
```

My input shape is (18 x 8) (18 time steps, 8 features).
My network currently consists of a convolutional layer (receptive field size=5, kernel=6), flatten layer, fully connected layer with 10 nodes and 1 output node. All activation functions are rectifier, except the output one, this is sigmoid.

I carefully checked the indices of my lists, they are correct. Sorry I can't upload all my data sets. If you have any idea what could be missing, I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: "loads my whole model for every classification" - what exactly do you mean with this? If you called `model.save(..)` or have a `ModelCheckpoint(...)` in your train callback list, then you have the optimal weights saved in the disk. You can define your model's architecture inside a function (say, `build_model(...)`) and simply call `model.load_weights(...)` to restore it to what it was.